# Adding an error message before restarting loop in c#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to add an error message that says "Please enter a non-zero or non-negative number" before my loop asks the user for input again. Here is what I have right now. Any text I try seems to only appear when the user inputs the correct number. Here is what I have right now.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double length;
        bool isInteger = false;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Length: ");
            isInteger = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length);
        }
        while (!(isInteger && length >= 0));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You have input: " + length);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        {
            double width;
        bool isInteger2 = false;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Width: ");
            isInteger2 = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out width);
        }
        while (!(isInteger2 && width >= 0));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You have input: " + width);
        Console.WriteLine();
            {
                double height;
        bool isInteger3 = false;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Height: ");
            isInteger3 = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out height);
        }
        while (!(isInteger3 && height >= 0));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You have input " + height);
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
double length;
bool success;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Length: ");
    success = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length) && (length > 0);
    if (!success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a non-zero or non-negative number");
    }
}
while (!success);
```

Comment: It's unclear to me if 0 (zero) is supposed to be a valid input or not. If it is, change `(length > 0)` to `(length >=0)`.

Comment: I appreciate this! I ended up going with this and it works perfectly for what I was trying to do. Also yeah zero was not supposed to be a valid input and I had caught that error too haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If open to using a open source NuGet package [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.46.1-preview.0.4)

```
internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double length = GetDouble("Please Enter Length:");
        double width = GetDouble("Please Enter Width:");
        double height = GetDouble("Please Enter Height:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Length {length} Width {width} Height {height}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static double GetDouble(string title) =>
        AnsiConsole.Prompt(
            new TextPrompt<double>(title)
                .PromptStyle("white")
                .Validate(input => input switch
                {
                    < 1 => ValidationResult.Error("[cyan]1 is min value[/]"),
                    _ => ValidationResult.Success(),
                }));
}
```

[image]